# How to parse the string in to different arraylist of string type

Tags: java, arraylist, string-parsing

I have string which contains 4 things and i want to store each thing in a list.
The string contains food orders which is coming from android to server, and in server i have to parse it to display.
The string looks like:

```
[:ordername:ordertime:orderprice: orderquantity:]
```

For 1 order case I want to enter ordername in name list and ordertime in time list and orderprice in pricelist and so on
If more than 1 order will come it will be separated by commas like

```
[:ordername:ordertime:orderprice:orderquantity:],[:ordername2:ordertime2:orderprice2:orderquantity2:]
```

I want to enter `ordername`,`ordername2` in name list and `ordertime`, `ordertime2` in time list and `orderprice` , `orderprice2` in price list and so on.

this is what i have tried

```
String orderlist=request.getParameter("orderlist"); // this is a string which is coming from android to server containing orders

char[] orderarray=orderlist.toCharArray(); //converting string to char array
int comma_counter = 0;
int comma_counter1 = 0;

for (int i=0; i < orderlist.length(); i++){
    if (orderarray[i]==','){
    comma_counter++;
}

}
      System.out.println("counter is"+comma_counter);
      System.out.println("order list length"+orderlist.length());


ArrayList <String> order_array_list = new ArrayList <String>();

int no=0;

String temp="";

    for (int j=no; j<orderarray.length; j++){
    System.out.println(" j is "+ j); 


        if(orderarray[j]!=','){
            temp = temp+orderarray[j];
           // System.out.println("temp is "+temp);

        }
        else if(orderarray[j]==','){
        order_array_list.add(temp); 
        temp="";
           no=j;
        }
      }
    String []parts= null;
    for(int i=0; i<order_array_list.size(); i++){
        String array= order_array_list.get(i);

        parts= array.split(":");

        for(int j=0; j<parts.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(parts[j]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It makes no sense to convert the `String` to a `char` array. The `String` class has convenient methods (like `split()`) that will do exactly what you need.

Comment: when i have used split() method than all indexes of array were mixed up and they are difficult to put in to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
Map <Integer, List <String>> map = new HashMap <>();

// Initialize the map
map.put(1, new ArrayList <String> ());
map.put(2, new ArrayList <String> ());
map.put(3, new ArrayList <String> ());
map.put(4, new ArrayList <String> ());

String str = "[:ordername:ordertime:orderprice:orderquantity:]," + 
             "[:ordername2:ordertime2:orderprice2:orderquantity2:]";

// loop through each order set
for (String s: str.split(","))
{
    // remove any leading and trailing spaces
    s = s.trim();

    // remove the brackets 
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");

    int i = 1;

    // loop through each order component
    for (String c: s.split(":"))
    {
        // remove any leading and trailing spaces
        c = c.trim();
        if (c.length() > 0)
        {
            map.get(i).add(c);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(map);
```

**Outputs**:

> {1=[ordername, ordername2], 2=[ordertime, ordertime2], 
>    3=[orderprice, orderprice2], 4=[orderquantity, orderquantity2]}

**Note**: For simplicity, I'm using a `HashMap` to contain all the Lists, but you can create the 4 lists outside of a `HashMap` if you wish. In that case, you would need to have `if/else if` conditions in the `if (c.length() > 0)` statement.

Comment: can you please explain me more that how can i use if/else in if(c.length() > 0) statement

Answer (score 1):

May this code will help you

```
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;

       public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String input = "[:ordername:ordertime:orderprice:orderquantity:],                            [:ordername2:ordertime2:orderprice2:orderquantity2:]";

input = input.replace("[:", "");
input = input.replace(":]", "");

String[] inputArray = input.split(",");

List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> priceList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> quantityList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String order : inputArray) {
  String[] orderDetails = order.split(":");
  nameList.add(orderDetails[0]);
  timeList.add(orderDetails[1]);
  priceList.add(orderDetails[2]);
  quantityList.add(orderDetails[3]);
}
    }
    }
```

If you more concern about performance you can use apache commons for replacing string.